# Changing the background of LinearLayout with position

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout and I want to change the background with the position, it changes right the first time, but then it gets random afterwards. I'm using RecyclerView and ButterKnife.

```
public class MesesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{


private List<String> mesesList;
private Activity context = null;


public MesesAdapter(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
    String[] meses = {"Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho",
            "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"};
    mesesList = Arrays.asList(meses);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.meses, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) viewHolder;

    String mes = mesesList.get(position);

    holder.meses.setText(mes);

    if (position % 2 == 0)
        holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mesesList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.mes)
    TextView meses;
    @BindView(R.id.linear)
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}}
```

here the image that shows how the view is after
[in this image shows the positions 0, 1, 2 and 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCwvl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Views are recycled as you scroll. A new item on an odd position may reuse a view from an even position resulting in everything having grey background after a while.

#### Quick fix

The quick and dirty way to fix it is to add the else branch and explicitly say that odd items should have transparent background:

```
if (position % 2 == 0) {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
} else {
    holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(0); // Transparent.
}
```

> Note: `setBackgroundColor(0)` is better than `setBackground(null)` for performance as long as you only use `setBackgroundColor` method for setting background on the view.

This will not be enough if you use `RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItemMoved`. That method does not cause `onBindViewHolder` to be called on any items.

#### Correct way

The correct approach stems from the fact that, in your case, background color of the item view does not reflect the data item in any way. Whether an item view has grey background depends on the ordering, not on each individual item.

This is what `ItemDecoration` is for. For example:

```
public class EvenOddItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    @ColorInt private final int mOddColor;
    @ColorInt private final int mEvenColor;

    // Do not allocate objects in onDraw method! Prepare what we need here.
    private final Rect mTempRect = new Rect();
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public EvenOddItemDecoration(@ColorInt final int oddColor, @ColorInt final int evenColor) {
        mOddColor = oddColor;
        mEvenColor = evenColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(final Canvas c, final RecyclerView parent, final RecyclerView.State state) {
        for (int i = 0, size = parent.getChildCount(); i < size; i++) {
            final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            // Get index of the item this view represents.
            final int adapterPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);
            // Pick appropriate background color.
            if (adapterPosition % 2 == 0) {
                // Index 0, 2, 4... / First, third, fifth... items / Odd items
                mPaint.setColor(mOddColor);
            } else {
                // Index 1, 3, 5... / Second, fourth, sixth... items / Even items
                mPaint.setColor(mEvenColor);
            }
            // Get position of child view in the RecyclerView.
            parent.getDecoratedBoundsWithMargins(child, mTempRect);
            // Offset if it's dragging or animating.
            mTempRect.offset((int)child.getTranslationX(), (int)child.getTranslationY());
            // Draw the background!
            c.drawRect(mTempRect, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Hook it up like this:

```
list.addItemDecoration(new EvenOddItemDecoration(0, Color.GRAY);
```

You may use and alter the code as it fits your needs.